Is it possible install specific numpy version without removing orignal one
My numpy is currently 1.24. However, some packages (like sktime) require a lower version or the error message pops out
AttributeError: module 'numpy' has no attribute 'long'

I am not a fans of conda or virtual environment but I would like to know if there is any other way to do that
Any ideas?

Why are you not a fan of something that is specifically designed for what you want to do, which is having different versions of a library.

The short answer is no, of course not.  Each Python has one library.  If you don't have any packages that need the 1.24 version, which is likely, just uninstall it and go backwards.

Virtualenv is the way to go for that, and a rather clean way. Nix can be used too but if you do not like virtualenv, then you might not like nix too.

Are you "not a fan" because you do not understand how virtual environments operate? As the first comment says, this is exactly the situation they are designed to address, and they're a core part of Python. If you spend some time getting comfortable with them, and perhaps investigating higher-level tools like pipenv, you will find that they are a relatively simple solution.

theoretically if you would install another Python in different folder then it should have own folder for modules and you could install different version in this Python, and use this Python with this module to run code. But this need to remember to always use /full/path/to/new/python to run code with new Python, and it needs to install all other modules in new Python (and it may also need to use /full/path/to/new/python -m pip ...). So using venv is simpler.
